# show datetime in text format in php

Tags: php, ajax

> i want to show datetime in the format March 03, 2017 T 07:30:00

this is my script

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            var from = "";
            $('#loadings').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'http://apis.fdf.df/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/<?php 
                echo $number; ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#loadings').hide();
                    console.log(response);                        
                    document.getElementById('ldate').innerHTML = 
                    response[0].DATE;
                    }, error: function (errors) {
                    console.log(errors);//alert('hi');                    
                    $('#loadings').hide();
                    $('#error').html("<h2><span style='color:red;'>No data 
                    found on this LR No.</span></h2>");                     
                }
                });
                });
             </script>
```

> my api's console output is

```
[{"DATE":"2017-04-03T00:00:00","lrConfirmStatus":null,"lrLoadStatus":null}]
```

> i want to bind it to the field with id "ldate"

```
                     <tr>
                        <td>LOAD  DATE:</td>
                        <td id="ldate"> </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is the `fdf.df` server yours? You can't change the response of a client-side request with a server-side technology.

Comment: Do you want PHP or JavaScript to format the datetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to your success

```
$("#ldate").append(response[0]["DATE"])
```

Comment: format will be wrong. And you should use text() or html(). You can't append a string like its a html tag

Answer (score 2):

You need a function that format your date. formatDate function format date by you want:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var from = "";
        $('#loadings').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://apis.fdf.df/api/Get_Loadsheet_Details/<?php 
            echo $number; ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#loadings').hide();
                console.log(response);                        
                document.getElementById('ldate').innerHTML = formatDate(response[0].DATE);
            }, 
            error: function (errors) {
                console.log(errors);//alert('hi');                    
                $('#loadings').hide();
                $('#error').html("<h2><span style='color:red;'>No data found on this LR No.</span></h2>");                     
            }
        });
    });

    function formatDate(date_string) {
        var date = new Date(date_string);
        var monthNames = [
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December"
        ];

        var day = date.getDate();
        var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getFullYear();

        if(day < 10) {
            day = '0'+day;
        }

        return  monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + day  + ', ' + year + ' T ' + date.getHours()+':' + date.getMinutes() +':' +date.getSeconds();
    }
</script>
```